# Another word for Non-Photographic

Tags: word-choice, image-identification, photography

Some of the [desktop wallpapers I have](https://vrty.org/user/~lonniebiz/) are photographs and some of them are "non-photographic"; meaning they are not the product of a camera,but are instead the product of someone "drawing with a computer" or "generating graphics using a computer".

Is there a term that means what I'm trying to say besides "non-photographic"? I'd like to tag all my wallpapers (that are not photos) with the correct term.

**UPDATE:** I decided to label these wallpaper: "[CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-generated_imagery)" (which is an abbreviation for: [Computer Generated Imagery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-generated_imagery)). Ultimately, I concluded it is better to label something by **"what it is"** than by **"what it is not"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Synthetic***.

From MW dictionary:

> **[synthetic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synthetic)**:  devised, arranged, or fabricated for special situations to imitate or replace usual realities; **factitious**
>
> **[factitious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/factitious)**: produced by humans rather than by natural forces

Answer (score 2):

I would personally tag such images as *[illustrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illustration)*.  Should you wish to be more specific, you might consider tagging them as *[digital illustrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_illustration)*.

Comment: To me, "illustration" seems too instructional-sounding on first thought. It makes me think of a diagram more than an artistic wallpaper that is not a photo.

Answer (score 1):

You might call it *computer-generated* unless you think that it might undermine the creative work involved because *computer-generated* sometimes refers to something that is an end result of being processed by a computer and requires no effort by an artist (other than waiting for the render to complete).

In that case you may simply refer to it as *digital artwork*.

Comment: I don't disagree with the term *digital artwork*, but the term seems ambiguous to me in this context.  The vast majority of photographs in the linked album have been *heavily* altered via digital tools.

Comment: @Sculper : You are probably correct that even the photos have been modified to some extent with computers, but I'm specifically interested in tagging the images that don't seemingly have any elements of photography in them.

Comment: I think I know what you're getting at. Have you heard of vector graphics?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics

Comment: @shaunxer Yes, to me "vector graphic" emphasizes that the image can be resized without loss of quality (not so for these wallpapers). Your thoughts about "computer-generated" are keen. "Digital Artwork" doesn't necessarily emphasize the complete absence of photography, though it is the best suggestion so far (to me).

Comment: That's true but it can also refer to images that started as vector.  I'll keep looking for a better term anyway.

Comment: Here's a term that may be at least a bit better than Digital art- Computer art https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_art